# How to browser all rows and rename with custom name in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, foreach

I have List<> image contain like:

```
C:/aljaslfk.jpg
C:/blakjfiowi.jpg
```

And I want to rename this with variable `name + i` like

```
C:/alias 1.jpg
C:/alias 2.jpg
```

How to create `alias 1 with items 1`, `alias 2 with item 2`?

My code like:

```
List<string> lstNameImage = new List<string>();
List<string> lstAliasImage = new List<string>();
for (int i = valuesFrom; i < valuesTo; i++)
{
    values = name + " " + i;
    lstAliasImage.Add(values);
}
for (int i = 0; i < lstImgAdded.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string imgPath = lstImgAdded.Items[i].Text;
    lstNameImage.Add(imgPath);
}
foreach (var alias in lstAliasImage)
{
    foreach (var items in lstNameImage)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(items);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        g.DrawImage(DrawText(alias, new Font(cbxFont.Text, fontSize), colorInput, Color.Transparent), new Point(350, 160));
        g.Dispose();
        ScaleImage(img, witdhImg, heightImg).Save(@"img\hinhmau\" + alias + "." + cbxImgType.Text, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        picPreview.Image = img;
        picPreview.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

[image: Is list image I want rename]
[image: After rename it will look like]

I was write text in image, but I only know how to rename with image 1 to `name 01`, image 2 to `name 02` I will resolve my problem.

Comment: not sure what you are trying to accomplish, you ask how to rename files? but your code loads each image in lstNameImage and saves it the number of times there is items in lstAliasImage ?

Comment: Why are you disposing `g` in `foreach`?

Comment: I was update my question.

Comment: I think `g` must `Dispose()` after `DrawText()`

Comment: You shouldn't touch the very elements you are iterating over in a *foreach* loop. Either you have to copy them first or you use an "oldschool" *for* loop.

Comment: Yup, I was edited my question to a describe highline problem.

Comment: My problem is the only loop in ` the second foreach`. First foreach is only loop in 1 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `File.Move(oldPath, newPath)` inside a `for` loop. If I got it right, you want to replace each filename with the equivalent name at the same in dex in `lstAliasImage`.

You can delete `lstAliasImage`. In my code you will overwrite `lstNameImage` with you new names.

```
List<string> lstNameImage = new List<string>();
//List<string> lstAliasImage = new List<string>(); <-- no need anymore

for (int i = 0; i < lstNameImage.Count; i++)
{
    string newFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(lstNameImage[i]) + "\\" + name + " " + i;
    File.Move(lstNameImage[i], newFile);
    lstNameImage[i] = newFile;
}

for (int i = 0; i < lstImgAdded.Items.Count; i++)
{
    string imgPath = lstImgAdded.Items[i].Text;
    lstNameImage.Add(imgPath);
}

//foreach (var alias in lstAliasImage) <-- also no need anymore
//{
    foreach (var items in lstNameImage)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(items);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        g.DrawImage(DrawText(alias, new Font(cbxFont.Text, fontSize), colorInput, Color.Transparent), new Point(350, 160));
        g.Dispose();
        ScaleImage(img, witdhImg, heightImg).Save(@"img\hinhmau\" + alias + "." + cbxImgType.Text, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        picPreview.Image = img;
        picPreview.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
//}
```